# Behavior of a contract created from another contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

If I call `getterA()` from contract `B` the result is `0`. Can someone explain me why? In my opinion it has to be `2`, because I set it to `2`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract A {

    uint private a;

    function setA(uint _a) external { a = _a; }
    function getA() external view returns(uint) { return a; }
}

contract B {
    A a;

    constructor() public {
        a = new A();

        a.setA(2);
    }

    function getterA() public view returns(uint) { a.getA(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've got this behaviour because you have forgotten to use a return in your getter :

```
function getterA() public view returns(uint) { return a.getA(); }
```

Comment: What a stupid mistake! Thanks a lot. One additional question, `a` contains the address to the instance of `A`. So I could also replace `A a` with `address a` and would get the same behaviour, right?

Comment: if you use only address you have to use call (construct manualy the call) contract_address.call(bytes4(sha3("function_name(arguments types)")),10);
but when you use the contract name+abstract form you can call directly the functions (ABI)